# How to blink browser window with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, browser

I have a request every 10 seconds to check whether there is something new and if there is, I want the window to blink so that the user gets notified immediately. 
How can I do that in GWT?

Comment: *"I want the window to blink so that the user gets notified"*  As a user I do not want my browser 'blinking' at me.  A JS alert is enough to get my attention.  Anything more is a signal to 'close that page immediately'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: even better than a JS alert (which to me is the same kind of _signal_), use Web Notifications: http://caniuse.com/notifications, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/

Comment: @AndrewThompson: The problem with the JS alert is, that it is blocking. So if I make a JS Alert, the whole application is blocked until the user clicks ok. Is there a way to automatically close the JS alert window after x seconds? (within GWT)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: It's not supported in most browsers... So not useful at all :-(

Comment: Please define : *I want the window to blink*

Comment: I want that it blinks in the task bar if on another window and the tab blink if on another tab.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in place of you I would like to use 

**Server-Push(Reverse ajax)**,

**Long polling Comet enabled approach**.

Don't annoy user by refreshing page..:)
Here the link which can help you out.

[GWT-COMET INTEGRATION](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: that is what i am trying to say man that you don't need to blink the window for notifications.